# How to convert code values to human readable values?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I my application a lot of columns are filled by machine-friendly code. For example the `status` column may have 20 status code e.g. `f` and `c` values instead of `Finished` and `Current`. How can I convert  this code easily to its natural counterparts while fetching from db?

**I want to create a view for each table, in views I need a natural column for each code column, `table.status`-> `view.statusText`**

Update:

Currently I am storing natural values on following table and join each table with this.

```
CREATE TABLE `constant` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` CHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE ,
    `value` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE ,
    `category` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Here is a example of such views.

```
SELECT program.*,ct.text AS typeText,cs.text as subjectText, count(programId) as enrollerCount,e.fullName as entityFullName, 
if(now()>enrollmentEndDate,'a',if(now()<enrollmentStartDate,'b','c') ) as enrollmentStatus ,
if(now()>executionEndDate,'a',if(now()<executionStartDate,'b','c') ) as executionStatus,
ts.text as executionStatusText
FROM program
left join enroller on program.id=programId
LEFT JOIN constant ct ON `type`=ct.value
left join constant cs on `subject`=cs.value 
left join entitylist e on e.id=program.entityId
left join constant ts on if(now()>executionEndDate,'a',if(now()<executionStartDate,'b','c') )=ts.value and ts.category='timeStage'
WHERE (ct.category='programType' OR ct.category IS NULL)
and (cs.category='subject' OR cs.category IS NULL)
group by program.id
```

Is there any way to make view cleaner and more maintainable?

Comment: You can use `case-when` for this in mysql, provide some sample data so that we can give the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN status='f' THEN 'Finished'
         WHEN status='c' THEN 'Current'
       END AS status
...
```

Comment: That hard-codes the status meaning into any number of SQL queries that will be cut-and-pasted through the lifetime of the application.  Quite brittle.

Comment: @EricJ., true, when I posted my answer, the question did not have the part about creating a view for every table, so I supposed he wanted something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Most commonly you would have a lookup table that provides the friendly version of the codes.  If you main table was

```
CREATE TABLE Main
(
    Id    INT,
    Code  CHAR(1)
);
```

you could have a lookup table

```
CREATE TABLE Lookup
(
    Code CHAR(1),
    English VARCHAR(50) -- for example
);
```

Then you could

```
SELECT * FROM Main m INNER JOIN Lookup l ON l.Code = m.Code
```

The SQL syntax is SQL Server, but should be the same or quite close for MySQL.

**UPDATE**

You can create a view based on the above join to simplify coding

I think the MySQL syntax would be something like

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM Main m INNER JOIN Lookup l ON l.Code = m.Code
```

Then you could

```
SELECT English FROM MyView WHERE Id=42 -- Or however you are selecting your rows
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: +1 This in deed the best solution since if new codes are added the query does not need to be changed and just need to add the new code in the lookup table.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: This can also be expanded slightly to provide multi-lingual support.

Comment: Indeed currently I am using this method. The problem is that for each column I have to write a join statement.

Comment: Exactly !! Having display values in a lookup table is always is a good idea to facilitate many operations without having to worry about the query.

Comment: @PHPst: You can create a view that hides the complexity of the join, to simplify your code.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only suggestion I can think of is another table within your schema. A `category` table.

```
CREATE TABLE Category(
categoryID    INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
categoryType  VARCHAR(6),
categoryCD    VARCHAR(12),
categoryDesc  VARCHAR(255),
createdDate   DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
```

Something along those lines, where categoryType is the type of category (there could be multiple categories with similar machine readable codes) categoryCd is the code (say 'f' or 'c') and categoryDesc is the Human description. This method, of course, will make you hit another table in your queries to fetch the human readable code.

So for a quick example

```
categoryID: 1
categoryType: "ORDER"
categoryCD: "C"
categoryDesc: "Cancelled"

categoryID: 2
categoryType: "ORDER"
categoryCD: "F"
categoryDesc: "Finished"

categoryID:3
categoryType: "QUOTE"
categoryCD: "C"
categoryDesc: "Completed"
```

You'd link your tables to the category table by using the category type

```
SELECT G.categoryDesc FROM table A, category G
WHERE G.categoryType = 'ORDER' AND G.categoryCD = A.categoryCD
```

Hopefully that helps?